# Pivot Table Code, Need some ideas

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008-r2, pivot

I'm working on a Pivot problem. I came up with some code, but have been unsuccessfull in working out the coding. Please could someone give me some guidance on what I'm doing wrong here?

I have table 1, which is create in code below:

```
create table T1 (
     [name]  varchar(30)
    ,[size]  int
    ,[DT]  date)

 insert into T1 values ( 'x1', 14,  '01/03/2013' );
 insert into T1 values ( 'x1', 134, '01/04/2013' );
 insert into T1 values ( 'x1', 199, '01/05/2013' );
 insert into T1 values ( 'x1', 284, '01/06/2013' );
 insert into T1 values ( 'x2', 212, '01/03/2013' );
 insert into T1 values ( 'x2', 369, '01/04/2013' );
 insert into T1 values ( 'x2', 439, '01/05/2013' );
 insert into T1 values ( 'x2', 555, '01/06/2013' );
```

I need to Pivot the table into this format:

```
    01/03/13  01/04/2013    01/05/2013   01/16/2013
X1    14            134        199         284
X2    212           369        439         555
```

Here is the code I've been working on, but been unsuccessful in working it into the above output? Any ideas or pointers for me? Thanks in advance...

```
declare @DateList as varchar(max)
declare @dynamic_PQ as varchar(max)

select @DateList = 
  stuff(      (
select DISTINCT  
      ', '+ Quotename(CONVERT(VARCHAR(10),DT,110))
    from
    (       select dt  from t1 ) t
   for xml path ('')
   ),1,1,'')

  select @DateList 

 set @dynamic_PQ = 'select [GuestID], ' + @DateList + 
  ' from
    (
    Select [name],
      size,
      STUFF((SELECT distinct '', '' + convert(a2.size as varch(10))
               from t1 a2
               where src.name = a2.name
                  and src.dt = a2.dt
                  FOR XML PATH(''''), TYPE
                  ).value(''.'', ''NVARCHAR(MAX)'') 
              ,1,1,'''') answer
    from
    (
      select name,
        dt ,
        size
      from t1
    ) src
   ) as S
   PIVOT

   (
    MAX([size])
    for Question IN (' + @DateList + ')
   ) as P

   Exec(@dynamic_PQ)
```

PS: If there is something special you have to do to get anyone to answer/respond to your post, please feel free to share it in your response.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have unclosed quotation marks, extra unneeded brackets, whole part with STUFF FOR XML inside dynamic sql is not needed (for output described), there was wrong column name...

```
declare @DateList as varchar(max)
declare @dynamic_PQ as varchar(max)

select @DateList = 
  stuff(      (
select DISTINCT  
      ', '+ Quotename(CONVERT(VARCHAR(10),DT,110))
    from
    (       select dt  from t1 ) t
   for xml path ('')
   ),1,1,'')

  --select @DateList 

 set @dynamic_PQ ='SELECT * from
    (
      select name,
        dt ,
        size
      from t1
    ) as S
   PIVOT
   (
    MAX([size])
    for DT IN ('+ @DateList +')
   ) as P'



   EXEC (@dynamic_PQ)
```

**[SQLFiddle DEMO](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/3638d/21)**

Answer (score 0):

Your query has multiple errors.  This version works:

```
select [name], [01-03-2013], [01-04-2013], [01-05-2013], [01-06-2013]
from ( Select [name], size,
       STUFF((SELECT distinct ', ' + cast(a2.size as varchar(10))
              from t1 a2
              where src.name = a2.name and src.dt = a2.dt
              FOR XML PATH(''), TYPE ).value('.', 'NVARCHAR(MAX)') ,1,1,''
              ) as question
       from ( select name, dt , size
              from t1
            ) src
     ) S
PIVOT ( MAX([size]) for Question IN ([01-03-2013], [01-04-2013], [01-05-2013], [01-06-2013])
      )as pvt;
```

You should debug this by printing out the SQL and running it.  Here are a few of the problems:

- You use `question` in the pivot but define `answer` in the code.
- The expression `convert(a2.size as varch(10))` is non-sensical SQL
- The `pivot` statement requires an alias
- The column `GuestId` is not defined

Answer (score 0):

Here is a simple query

```
select name, [01-03-2013], [01-04-2013], [01-05-2013], [01-06-2013] from
        (select  name, size, DT from T1)a
        PIVOT(sum(size) for DT in ([01-03-2013], [01-04-2013], [01-05-2013], [01-06-2013])) as pvt
```